# Why adding a new instance does not increase memory in azure?

Tags: azure

today my site WAS SUSPENDED because out of memory (I am in the SHARED mode - Trial period). So, I had to wait almost a hour to see my site work again.

But a site should never be down and never for such a long time.

Moreover, I have very low traffic (and the lack of memory surprised me a lot) in this first stage.  When I went out of memory, I immediately scaled my resources. First of all, I tried to add an instance (passing to 2) but the memory was still 512MB and i was not able to see any change in the resource allocated. So, i passed to reserved but it was still SUSPENDED.

Question: is it possible to remain in the shared mode and increase the resources? Why if i add instances i cannot see any difference to my resources (showed in the dashboard)? How can i be notified if my site is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing website instance does not increase resources. It only increases the number of load balanced copies of your website.  Resources are not shared across instances.  If you are doing extensive caching, then you probably need to move to a Cloud Service Web Role.

Websites are extremely limited.  They are for the most basic of sites.  If your site is exceeding 512mb of memory with low usage, and you want to stay on Azure websites, then you need to do some profiling and see what in your app is eating up resources.